# How to use email instead of username using Nestjs passport

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication using passport with nestJS, the default implementation works flawlessly.
In my case i would like to use "email" instead of username but unfortunately the validate function which resides inside local.strategy.ts accepts only "username" and will not even invoke without username parameter.
Please advice.

reference to the implementation I've used, I followed the guide step by step

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

Comment: `JwtStrategy`'s `constructor`, try `super({ usernameField: "email" })`

Answer (score 7):

I would agree with Micael Levi. Just provide these parameters in the constructor to the parent class

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  super({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
  });
}
```

You can further read the docs here https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#customize-passport

Hope This Helps

Comment: exactly the problem i was running into. thanks!

Comment: How do you specify custom credentials?

Comment: @Soubriquet Do you know how I can specify custom credentials, please? I want to do it like `customField: 'serviceName'`